# No Auto Variables Debugging Python in VS2019

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2019

I like VS2019 and I want to do as much dev on it without needing to switch IDEs constantly. To this, I tried coding in Python but when it came to debugging, it really hold no weight to Pycharm.
For one, the “Autos” variables don’t show on my end:
[image: No auto variales like it would show with c++ and c#]

This is with a project I created within VS2019. Instead to see variables, I have to go to the super cluttered “locals” tab which actually includes for whatever reason, collections, and a bunch of packages cluttering up my debug monitor. I can’t even take out these variables so I can have a cleaner window
In C++, Autos were automatically populated with variables within the scope of the current function call. In the locals everything including stuff I don’t care is there: 
[image: Local Variables overpopulated]

The worst part, making classes with multiple values, the object of the class in the debug window can’t even expan to show you the values the object holds like it does so well in Pycharm:
[image: Pycharm]

Is there a way to fix this? Different debug monitor windows you can use to make variable tracking as close to and intuitive as Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

​I fixed it by going to Tools->Options->Python->Debugging,  and changing it to "use legacy debugger". Unfortunately it doesn't track multipe variables on auto. Just the most recent one